# How to make Radio Button in Alert Dialog display very long text?

Tags: android

How do I make a Radio button display a really long label inside an AlertDialog?

```
String[] labels = new String[]{"My Super Long Label That Will Result in an ellipses Garbage 1234567890"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(labels, 0 , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

When I run the above code, it gets cut off rather than displaying it across multiple lines.

Comment: set the view of the dialog to a custom view rather than using the default one generated for you. `builder.setView(myViewWithRadioButtons)`.  perhaps your custom view will allow wrapping of text for radiobuttons

Comment: what's the point behind this limit ? single choice list item ctext can have maximun two lines.

Answer (score 0):

single choice list item text can have maximum two lines of text. can't find any sence what's the point behind this limit .
i guess to use your own adapter and pass it to `public AlertDialog.Builder setSingleChoiceItems (ListAdapter adapter, int checkedItem, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)` will be the only way.

ridiculous.

Comment: I guess they wanted keep the same margin/padding/height between radio icon

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. This is same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15036377/4279095)
solution, but instead of ***android:textSize*** here we need ***android:inputType***

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:inputType">textMultiLine</item>
</style>
```

Then use this:

```
ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme );
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder( cw );
```

Comment: it does nothing