# Reducing font size of AlertDialog.Builder's components

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view, android-fonts

I created an `AlertDialogue` using the following code :

```
 int selectedModeId=0;
 public void sortTypeModeSelection(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(WatchListDetailActivity.this);

    alertBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.watchlist_sorting_modes,selectedModeId, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case 0:
                    selectedModeId=0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selectedModeId=1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selectedModeId=2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    selectedModeId=3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    selectedModeId=4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    selectedModeId=5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    selectedModeId=6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    selectedModeId=7;
                    break;
            }
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertBuilder.show();
}
```

[image]

I made the alert, but I want to reduce the font size of the list items of the dialog. How can I do this?

**Note**: Don't recommend inflating a custom layout to accomplish this, I wish to know if there is another approach.

Comment: Curious: In your case, why not replace that switch statement with `selectedModeId = which`?

Comment: @kcoppock thank u. showing me that

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I was able to achieve this through styles. I added this style to my `styles.xml` file in the values directory:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Then when creating the `AlertDialog`, I wrapped the activity context in a `ContextThemeWrapper` and passed that into the `Builder` constructor:

```
ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme );
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder( cw );
```

This produced smaller text size for the list items in the dialog.

[image]

Comment: Do you, by chance, know how to reduce the height of each individual item to match the font size? Right now, even when reducing the font size, the items stay as large as before.

Comment: this changes the title text size too

Comment: It will reduce the title and button text size too.

Comment: Can only reduce the list text size?

Answer (score 6):

you have to use custom layout for this.

[image]

check below code it sure help you

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(forgatps.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select Your Account");

            builder.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(forgatps.this,
                    R.layout.row_email, R.id.textView1, emails),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            MainEmail = emails.get(which);
                            editEmail.setText("" + MainEmail);

                        }
                    });

            builder.show();
```

row file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How does this not use custom layout as asked by questioner?

Comment: i am asking is there any way to achieve this without using custom xmls

Comment: i dont think so, but you can start start bounty for this ans.

Answer (score 3):

Try out as below :

Its just a way i am showing you the way its possible.

> ```
>   final CharSequence[] itemsMark =
>    {getResources().getString(R.string.Mark_As_Beautiful),
>               getResources().getString(R.string.Mark_As_Fun),
>               getResources().getString(R.string.Mark_As_Not_A_Portrait),
>               getResources().getString(R.string.Mark_As_Offensive),
>               getResources().getString(R.string.Mark_As_Spam),
>               getResources().getString(R.string.Mark_As_Cancel)
>    };
>    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> itemsAdapter = new
>    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> (this,
>             R.layout.menu_items, itemsMark);
>    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
>    builder.setTitle("My Title");
>    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
>    builder.setAdapter(itemsAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
>    {
>        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
>                   switch(item) {
>                           case 0:
>                       //Mark as Beautiful
>                           break;
>                        case 1:
>                       //Mark as Beautiful
>                           break;
>                     case 2: 
>                         //Mark as Not a Portrait
>                           break;
>                     case 3:
>                       //Mark as Offensive
>                           break;
>                    case 4:
>                       //Mark as Spam
>                           break;
>                    case 5:
>                       //cancel
>                    break;
>            }
>        }
>    });
> ```

### And in  layout/menu_items.xml :

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@android:id/text1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dip"
       android:layout_margin="5dip"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textSize="22dip"
       android:textColor="#ff000000"
       android:typeface="normal"
       android:lineSpacingExtra="0dip"/>
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: He said about not using custom layout in his alert dialog. Then how does this differ?

Comment: well i know this but i want to use radio button associated with text view how can i do this ? and it must show the selection?

Comment: i am asking is there any way to achieve this without using custom xmls

Comment: AFAIK my knowledge is concern it can be done by this way only.

Comment: how could i use check box along with textview inside alert view

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you would need to change the text size without using a custom layout file like shown in the present answers(unless you're maybe implementing some sort of accessibility option keeping the current platform's look and feel?). Anyway you could still modify the text size by directly modifying the dialog's list. Something like this:

```
private static int mTextSize = 5;
private static int mFirstVisible = -1;
private static int mLastVisible = -1;

v.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    changeCurrentVisibleSize(ad.getListView());
                    // ad is the AlertDialog resulted from alertBuilder.create
                    ad.getListView().setOnScrollListener(
                            new OnScrollListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onScrollStateChanged(
                                        AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                                        int firstVisibleItem,
                                        int visibleItemCount,
                                        int totalItemCount) {
                                    if (visibleItemCount != 0) {
                                        if (mFirstVisible != firstVisibleItem
                                                || mLastVisible != (firstVisibleItem
                                                        + visibleItemCount - 1)) {
                                            updateRow((ListView) view);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }

            });
```

where the `changeCurrentVisibleSize()` and `updateRow()` method are:

```
static void updateRow(ListView listView) {
    final int count = listView.getChildCount();
    final View firstRow = listView.getChildAt(0);
    final View secondRow = listView.getChildAt(count - 1);
    if (firstRow instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) firstRow).setTextSize(mTextSize);
        ((TextView) secondRow).setTextSize(mTextSize);
    }
}

static void changeCurrentVisibleSize(ListView listView) {
    final int count = listView.getChildCount();
    mFirstVisible = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    mLastVisible = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View rowView = listView.getChildAt(i);
        if (rowView instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) rowView).setTextSize(mTextSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Increasing the text should work fine, decreasing the text again should work fine(but in this case the row will continue to have a certain height based on the layout file used).