# How can I reduce the item row height in a single choice AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am relatively new to Android development. Using a number of answers here and articles elsewhere, I added an `AlertDialog` to my app with `setSingleChoiceItems`. I am displaying my items and I can get the user's item selection and button choice.

The default text size was too big for me and I was able to use the answer from: [Reducing font size of AlertDialog.Builder's components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888832/reducing-font-size-of-alertdialog-builders-components) to reduce the text size of my items.

The problem is that the item row height is the same as with the default text size.

My question is how can I also reduce the height of the item rows in my dialog?

I have looked for answers and tried adding "`android:layout_height`" and "`android:minHeight`" to my custom dialog theme `style.xml` but neither had any affect.

My dialog with default settings is

[image]

And my dialog with my `ContextThemeWrapper` is:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Those RadioButtons probably have default padding or margins. Try setting their padding to 0 and see if that allows the list items to have less height.

Comment: Thanks, David. I can't find the particular style for the radio button padding. Do you know what it is?

By the way, I tried to set `listPreferredItemHeight` to 32dip (the default seems to be 64dip) but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: RadioButton is a subclass of View so you can set android:padding, android:paddingBottom, android:paddingEnd, android:paddingLeft, android:paddingRight, android:paddingStart, or android:paddingTop .