# How can I set an AlertDialog item height?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

Currently on an Android 4.3 device. I'm using the excellent answer [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15036377/435093) I was able to reduce the font size of an `AlertDialog`'s individual items:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
</style>
```

The dialog itself is built with:

```
ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme );
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cw);
```

However, the problem is that the individual height of the items still stays the same — in fact, there is a fifth element that is just shown when you scroll in the dialog:

[image]

I tried [setting the `dividerHeight`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984313/spacing-between-listview-items-android) but that just increased the spacing. I also set the `layout_margin` property to `0dp` without success.

What's the correct style definition for this dialog to reduce the space between the labels?

Note that I do not want to build the whole dialog using a view again. I'd like to keep the existing AlertDialog.

Comment: You might be able to configure the list item height by specifying the dimensions to the android attributes `listPreferredItemHeight` (default) or `listPreferredItemHeightSmall` (Holo) in your theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a tricky solution – override the `getView` method for `ListView` in `AlertDialog` and change `TextView` style attributes programmatically:

```
ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cw);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        ListView listView = ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).getListView();
        final ListAdapter originalAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

        listView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return originalAdapter.getCount();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int id) {
                return originalAdapter.getItem(id);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int id) {
                return originalAdapter.getItemId(id);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int id) {
                return originalAdapter.getItemViewType(id);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = originalAdapter.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                //textView.setTextSize(16); set text size programmatically if needed
                textView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 32 /* this is item height */));
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public int getViewTypeCount() {
                return originalAdapter.getViewTypeCount();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return originalAdapter.hasStableIds();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return originalAdapter.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                originalAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);

            }

            @Override
            public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                originalAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                return originalAdapter.areAllItemsEnabled();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                return originalAdapter.isEnabled(position);
            }

        });
    }
});

dialog.show();
```